# Prevent Range Validator to show error message with regular expression validator in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation

I have one textbox with id `txtNumOfBooks` which I am validating against following 3 validators:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNumOfBooks" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter the number of books" SetFocusOnError="True" CssClass="style4" ValidationGroup="CreateVac">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNumOfBooks" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter the valid number" ValidationExpression="[0-9]\d*[0-9]" CssClass="style4" ValidationGroup="CreateVac">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNumOfBooks"
Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Number of books in a book shelf should be in range 1-100"
MaximumValue="100" MinimumValue="1" Type="Integer" CssClass="style4" ValidationGroup="CreateVac">
</asp:RangeValidator>
```

However,Whenever I entered characters in textbox both messages:

```
Please enter the valid number Number of books in a book shelf should be in range 1-100
```

are displayed.How can I avoid range validator showing its error message with regular expression validator message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found the answer.There is need to add a javascript function that removes unneccessary range validator message.The function is:

```
  function clearRangeMessagePosition() {
            if (document.getElementById('<%=RegularExpressionValidator1.ClientID %>').getAttribute('isValid') != true.toString()) {
                document.getElementById('<%=RangeValidator1.ClientID %>').innerText = "";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('<%=RangeValidator1.ClientID %>').innerText = "Please enter number of books in range 1-100";
            }
        }
```